# Prevent Socket.io from firing multiple times for each event

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to emit an event from my server to a client when a client clicks a button. The issue I'm having is that my client side code is getting executed multiple times for each time my server emits an event. How can I ensure that my client-side code fires only once for each event emitted by the server?

My client code looks like this:

```
socket.on('data', function(data) {   
  $('.button').on('click, function() {
    clientFunc(data)
  });
});
```

My server code looks like this:

```
serverFunc(json, function(data) {
  socket.emit('data', data);
});
```

In reading the Node documentation, it seems that I might need to [remove event listeners](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removelistener_event_listener), so that `clientFunc` is fired only once per event?

Comment: hello @turtle were you able to find the solution to your problem,